# Target-typed new expressions and implicit arrays

Tags: c#

I can write the following to initialize a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` in a field initializer:

```cs
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lst = new() {
    new("Key1", "Value1"),
    new("Key2", "Value2")
}
```

leveraging target-typed `new` expressions for both the containing `List<>` and the individual `KeyValuePair<>` structs.

Is it possible to similarly initialize an array? Target-typed `new` expressions can't be used for the array itself, because an array has to be initialized.

But the following -- using implictly-typed arrays -- doesn't compile:

```cs
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] arr = new [] {
    new("Key1", "Value1"),
    new("Key2", "Value2")
}
```

with:

> CS0826 No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the `new[]` part:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

KeyValuePair<string, string>[] arr =
{
    new("Key1", "Value1"),
    new("Key2", "Value2")
};
```

That's *only* valid as part of a variable declaration though, which allow an *array_initializer* as the initial value, without the need for an *array_creation_expression*. Variable declarations include fields, of course:

```cs
public class Test
{
    private readonly KeyValuePair<string, string>[] arr =
    {
        new("Key1", "Value1"),
        new("Key2", "Value2")
    };
}
```

Comment: what part of the code uses `System.Collections.Generic`?

Comment: @LeiYang: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<,>`

Comment: I was actually hoping for something I could use in a field initializer; otherwise I would just use `var`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: You *can* use it for a field initializer. A field initializer is part of a variable declaration. Have you tried it? (I'll edit my answer to demonstrate that.)